# How do I stop these turtle errors and what do they mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

After I run my program and then close the Turtle window, the Python shell gives me an error.

I'm trying to make a dotted line down the middle of the screen in a replication of pong. I'm pretty new to Python & Turtle.  I haven't really tried anything to fix it either.

Here is the code that gives me errors:

```py
import turtle as t

#creates screen & assigns it to 'screen'
screen = t.Screen()

#setiing up screen
screenSize = 500
screen.setup(screenSize, screenSize)

#variables
human = t.Turtle()
ai = t.Turtle()
border = t.Turtle()

spacing = 10

#assigns a path to paddle gif to 'paddle'
paddle = 'images/paddle.gif'

#adds 'paddle' to screen
screen.addshape(paddle)

#assigns 'paddle' to human & ai shape
human.shape(paddle)
ai.shape(paddle)

#penup
human.penup()
ai.penup()
border.penup()

#making border
border.hideturtle()
border.goto(0, 250)
border.pendown()
border.right(90)
x = 0

while x in range(int(screenSize/spacing)):

    border.forward(spacing)
    border.penup()
    border.forward(spacing)
    border.pendown()
```

Here's the error:

```
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 3, in <module>
    border.forward(spacing)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 1637, in forward
    self._go(distance)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 1605, in _go
    self._goto(ende)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 3158, in _goto
    screen._pointlist(self.currentLineItem),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 755, in _pointlist
    cl = self.cv.coords(item)
  File "<string>", line 1, in coords
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2469, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"error:
```

I want it to make a dotted line down the middle, and it does, but it gives me an error when I close the turtle screen.

Comment: What error(s) does it give you?

Comment: sorry forgot to add error

Comment: do i need to specify 'spacing' as an int?: int(spacing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that this is effectively an infinite loop:

```
 while x in range(int(screenSize/spacing)):
```

So when you close the window, you're breaking it in the middle of one of the commands in the loop.  The problem is you used `while` instead of `for`.  Here's how I might lay out this same code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# Declare constants
SCREEN_SIZE = 500
LINE_SPACING = 10
PADDLE_FILE = 'images/paddle.gif'

# Create screen & assign it
screen = Screen()

# Set up screen
screen.setup(SCREEN_SIZE, SCREEN_SIZE)

# Add 'paddle' to screen
screen.addshape(PADDLE_FILE)

# Initialize turtles
human = Turtle()
human.shape(PADDLE_FILE)
human.penup()

ai = Turtle()
ai.shape(PADDLE_FILE)
ai.penup()

border = Turtle()
border.hideturtle()
border.penup()

# Draw border
border.sety(250)
border.right(90)
border.pendown()

for _ in range(SCREEN_SIZE // (LINE_SPACING * 2)):
    border.forward(LINE_SPACING)
    border.penup()
    border.forward(LINE_SPACING)
    border.pendown()

screen.mainloop()
```